# SQL remove Dups and keep longer columns value

Tags: sql, sas

I have questions about **SQL** on **SAS**, and the problem would be similar to following.

```
ID|LName|FName|Address
1 |A    |B    |1 Street
1 |A    |B    |1 Street **APT 101**
2 |A    |B    |1 Street
2 |A    |B    |1 Street **APT 101**
```

is that possible to check ID first, then if address is longer than another one then keep the longer one?

---

Comment: Yes it's possible, see @Julio's solution which is likely the easiest. MAX() in SQL works on character variables. This assumes that you don't have multiple addresses that are similar and need one, otherwise it may not work as expected. Is length really how you want to verify the address?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative. A simple MAX and group by should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, lname, fname, max(address)
FROM test WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY id, lname, fname;
```

**[See demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a21080/1)**

**Warning:** Bear in mind that this will work with rows with same "base" address and extra text. For example:

```
insert into test values(1, 'A', 'B', '1 Street'); 
insert into test values(1, 'A', 'B', '1 Street APT 101'); 
insert into test values(1, 'A', 'B', '1 Street APT 101 Other APT 202'); 
insert into test values(1, 'A', 'B', '1 Street APT 101 Other APT 202 yet another APT 333');
etc.
```

However It will "fail" if you change the base address on the rows:

```
insert into test values(1, 'A', 'B', '1 Street APT 101'); 
insert into test values(1, 'A', 'B', '1 Street APT 2'); # This is shorter but will come up instead of the other.
```

However those would be 2 different addresses and not the same one with extra info. So discarding any of those (whatever) may not make sense anyway.

If this restriction does not apply on your input data, you can safely use the SQL.

If you instead need a SQL that will work by checking length, then the next SQL will work on mysql, mariadb, and SQLite. You'll have to check on your dbms.

```
SELECT id, lname, fname, address, max(t.len)
FROM (
  SELECT *, length(address) as len FROM test
  ORDER BY len DESC
  ) t
GROUP BY id, lname, fname
```

See Demo **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6d472/2)**.

Comment: What if an address had two texts, ie APT 001 and APT 10?

Comment: Then It would shamely fail :). However given the example input, the repeated rows do not seem to be like that, same base with additional text. Let's see what OP says. I'll add the warning to the answer

Comment: In my database, those address would more like 1 street, 1 street apt, and sometimes 1 king ave, and 1 king avenue. I think max(address) would do the trick, but I have to test it first! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a big tricky, but you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.address = (select t2.address
                   from t t2
                   where t2.id = t.id
                   order by length(t2.address) desc
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can row number over the data and order by the length of the Address column.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

It would be something like this:

```
select id 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Length(address) DESC)
    ,LName
    ,FName
    ,Address
from table_name;
```

Then just filter on row number = 1.

Comment: OVER/PARTITION are not valid in SAS SQL